# react-Native: Access child component function inside parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parent-child

Goal: Create a reusable OptionFan component that allows children as ChildButton components.
Issue: unable to access ChildButton's method "flyOut()" inside OptionFan(parent) component method "showOptions()"

in Option Fan component:

```
 showOptions = () => {
        let animations = this.props.children.map((child, i) => {
            this.refs.child.flyOut();
        });
        Animated.stagger(this.props.staggerDelay, animations).start();
    }
    renderOptions = () => {
       return this.props.children.map((child, i) => {
           return <ChildButton ref={child} siblings={this.props.children.length} key={i} icon={} number={i} size={} />

       })
    }
```

in ChildButton component:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.ref(this);
    }

flyOut = () => {
        const {number, size} = this.state;
        let offset = this.findChildCoordinates(number);
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.move,
            {toValue: offset}
        ).start();
    }
```

the desired method is unaccessible in code-suggestions,
what is incorrect in my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need bind them to your class. Change your `optionFan` Component like this:

`Option Fan:`

```
showOptions = () => {
    let animations = this.props.children.map((child, i) => {
        this.child.flyOut();
    });
    Animated.stagger(this.props.staggerDelay, animations).start();
}
renderOptions = () => {
   return this.props.children.map(i => {
       return <ChildButton ref={ Ref =>(this.child = Ref)} siblings={this.props.children.length} key={i} icon={} number={i} size={} />

   })
}
```

For more reference see this https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/909#issuecomment-252969542